Template-template parameters cause linking errors when specializing `std::formatter`
Note: This is a follow-up to my previous question, where I figured out how to properly separate the interface and implementation of a std::formatter specialization for a non-templated custom type (TL;DR: You can't use auto for the return type of a declaration, because then the compiler will be unable to deduce the return type. Explicit type the return type out, and it will work).

I have been trying to specialize std::formatter<T> for a basic templated custom type Vector3D<T>, but I'm receiving a linker error. Here is a minimal reproducible example:
vector.h defines the Vector3D<T> class and defines the std::formatter specialization, but only declares its format function.
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <format>

/* Define `Vector3D` */
template <typename T>
struct Vector3D {
    T x, y, z;
};

/* Declare specialization of `std::formatter` for `Vector3D<T>`. There is a reason I
want to use a template-template parameter; namely, because in the actual codebase, there
are several templated types nearly identical to `Vector3D` that could all potentially use 
the same `format` function. */
template <template <typename> class VectorType, typename T>
struct std::formatter<VectorType<T>> : public std::formatter<std::string> {
    auto format(
        const VectorType<T> &item,
        std::format_context &format_context
    ) const -> decltype(format_context.out());
};

#endif

vector.cpp includes vector.h and defines std::formatter<VectorType<T>>::format():
#include "vector.h"

/* Define `std::formatter<VectorType<T>>::format()` */
template <template <typename> class VectorType, typename T>
requires (std::is_same_v<VectorType<T>, Vector3D<T>>)
auto std::formatter<VectorType<T>>::format(const VectorType<T> &item, std::format_context &format_context)
    const -> decltype(format_context.out()) 
{
    return std::format_to(format_context.out(), "{} {} {}\n", item.x, item.y, item.z);
}

Finally, main.cpp attempts to std::format a value of type Vector3D:
#include "vector.h"

int main()
{
    std::format("{}\n", Vector3D<float>(1, 2, 3));
}

However, compiling this gives a linker error (an undefined reference error to the format function I thought I specialized above):
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test_cpp_project.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `void std::basic_format_arg<std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char> >::handle::_S_format<Vector3D<float> const>(std::basic_format_parse_context<char>&, std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char>&, void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt16basic_format_argISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE6handle9_S_formatIK8Vector3DIfEEEvRSt26basic_format_parse_contextIcERS4_PKv[_ZNSt16basic_format_argISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE6handle9_S_formatIK8Vector3DIfEEEvRSt26basic_format_parse_contextIcERS4_PKv]+0x56): undefined reference to `std::formatter<Vector3D<float>, char>::format(Vector3D<float> const&, std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char>&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status‘std::basic_format_arg<std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char> >&&’

Though, I've observed that adding an explicit template instantiation (template struct std::formatter<Vector3D<float>>;) in either vector.h or vector.cpp causes the code to compile and link correctly.
Can someone explain why all of this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Definitions of templated entities, including partial specializations, belong in header files.
